# Nozzle digging into print after filament change

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, change-filament

So I recently watched a YouTube video on using Cura to modify a G-code to pause at a certain height in order to change filament (using an Ender 3 Pro) first time I did it, it worked fine but now when I replace the filament with the second colour and resume the print the nozzle digs into the print and tears it up its like it forgets it has done the first 5 layers and goes down to the bed again, the bed hasn't been moved neither has the Z-axis. can anyone help? It's beginning to do my head in I'm just wasting material.

Comment: Do you actually see it move down after the filament change? Or is it possible that it just moved down while paused/parked for filament change? If it really is moving after the resume, it could be that the Cura plugin you're using is buggy and puts something bogus in the gcode that causes it.

Comment: Once I change the filament and click resume it reheats the nozzle and then resumes printing but when it does it moves down and digs into the print and tears it like it's trying to do layer 6 at layer 1

Comment: Are the steppers powered during the pause? Are you pressing so hard that the X-Z gantry moved down?

Comment: How do i tell if the steppers are powered or not? And I'm very careful to not move the x-z gantry I gently replace the filament I've even measured the gap between the nozzle and bed before and after to make sure it hasn't moved

Comment: Sounds like the plugin put bad gcode in.

Comment: If the steppers are powered you cannot turn them, they are locked. Maybe you can post a part of the G-code file so we can see if the pause script works. Post the code, e.g 20 lines, around the pause.